# T SQL case statement with primary and secondary order by parameter

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by, case

I have a problem with my SQL statement:
I use SELECT statement and then CASE when I use order by.

```
SELECT .....
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @sort = 'ND' THEN name END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'NA' THEN name END,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'AD' THEN (isAuthorized)  END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sor = 'AA' THEN (isAuthorized) END
```

isAuthorized is a BIT value, so I would like to use secondary order by there.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT .....
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @sort = 'ND' THEN name END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'NA' THEN name END,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'AD' THEN (isAuthorized, name )  END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'AA' THEN (isAuthorized, name ) END
```

But it doesn't work.

I use SQL server 2008.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want order the result set first by `name` and then by `isAuthorized` when `@sort = ND` use this query:

```
SELECT .....
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @sort = 'ND' THEN name END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sort = 'ND' THEN isAuthorized END
```

You can combine `CASE` clauses. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: I wanted the opposite, first by isAuthorized and then by name (as I sort by many columns). But your answer pointed me to the right direction as I didn't know how to combine more then one order by statement. Thanks a bunch ... rated up and marked as answer ;)